# Move whole row to start of flexbox container, but keep spacing on variable width of container

Tags: html, css, flexbox

What I want is moving the whole row of `<div class="item">` to the very left of `<div class='container'>`. So basically if you remove the `justify-content: space-evenly;` from the `.container` class. However, this removes the spacing between the `<div class="item">` which I want to keep.

So basically like this
[image]

Is there a way to move the whole row of `<div class="item"></div>` to the left of the `<div class='container'>` and keep the spacing at the same time? Note: a fixed value for something like `gap` is not possible, because the width of the container varies.

I have this setup https://jsfiddle.net/tfvw0ma2/1/

```css
.container {
  width: 100%;
  height: 50px;
  background-color: lightgray;
  display: flex;
  flex-direction: row;
  align-items: flex-start;
  justify-content: space-evenly;
}

.item {
  width: 50px;
  height: 30px;
  background-color: hotpink;
}
```

```html
<div class='container'>
  <div class="item"></div>
  <div class="item"></div>
  <div class="item"></div>
  <div class="item"></div>
  <div class="item"></div>
  <div class="item"></div>
  <div class="item"></div>
  <div class="item"></div>
  <div class="item"></div>
  <div class="item"></div>
  <div class="item"></div>
  <div class="item"></div>
</div>
```

Comment: I'm not perfectly sure to undersrtand what you are trying to achieve anyway it may be helpful to know that if you set `gap: 1px;` on a flex container, you enforce a fixed spacing

Comment: if instead you meant to have your flex items to start from the very beginning of their container, you may use `justify-content: space-between;`

Comment: the question is not easy to decode. The flex container guesses by itself the space between the items fulfilling the criteria gave into `justify-content` and taking into account their fixed width and their number. If you want to keep a resposive way to space the elements in an arbitrary large container while keeping the number of items fixed, you need to trust `justify-content: space-evenly/space-between/..` or use relative units. In the first case the spacing is unknown and decided in real time so you can't add anything upfront..

Comment: you can't add a meaningful `transform: translate(x, y)` on the flex items nor use an external container with left padding because you don't know up front how much will be the spacing. So if you want to rely on known facts like the number of items, their width and the total availalble width, you may just "calculate" the spacing in terms of `vw` or `%` and use that amount in `gap` forcing the flex flow to start from the beginning and keep a fixed (relative!) gap between items

Answer (score 0):

```
.item {
    display:flex
    justify-content: flex-start;
    gap: 10px;
}
```

Comment: Please don't post only code as answer, but also provide an explanation what your code does and how it solves the problem of the question. Answers with an explanation are usually more helpful and of better quality, and are more likely to attract upvotes.